# Fancybox JavaScript XMLHttpRequest request binary data

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I make a XMLHttpRequest with a customer header to another domain. I get back data that can be text or binary. I like to show the data like text, image, pdf etc. in fancybox and a download box if the data cannot be displayed.

Below is the code I use. Text is displayed OK, but the image is displayed as text.

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();

invocation.open('GET', URL, false);
invocation.setRequestHeader("Authorization", $.trim(header)); 
invocation.send(); 

$.fancybox({
    'autoSize': true,
    'enableEscapeButton' : true,
    'overlayShow' : true,
    'overlayOpacity' : 0,
    'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
    'content' : invocation.response,
    'type':invocation.getResponseHeader('content-type')
});
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: what does `invocation.response` return? you could try `$.fancybox(invocation.response{//options})` instead (no `content` option by the way)